# AWS SQS Server Side Encryption

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-sqs

I'm trying to encrypt the SQS messages using SSE. I have enabled SSE for the queue. Is there a way to see the encrypted message in the queue? When I view the message using view/delete message it shows the decrypted message. How do I verify that the message is really encrypted?

Comment: _Why_ do you wish to do this?

Comment: Just to ensure that my SSE config is right and it is indeed encrypting the messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to see the encrypted version of the message.

Server-Side Encryption means that data is **encrypted at rest**. It means that if anybody were to access the raw disk, they would be unable to read the data because it is encrypted. When you view a message, it is retrieved and automatically decrypted.